# Hibernate validation no validation

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, spring-3, hibernate-validator

Hi i am following an example I found

```
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/
```

The problem is that no errors are found in my profile that I post. I should be. Why can this happend?

```
@Test
@Ignore
public void anotherTest() {
    Profile profile = ProfileUtil.getProfile();

    profile.setEmail("user@mail.com");
    profile.setSex("dafjsgkkdsfa");
    BindingResult bindingResult = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(profile, "profile");
    userController.postUser(new ModelMap(), profile, bindingResult);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("errors");
    }

    assertTrue(bindingResult.hasErrors());

    profileService.deleteProfile(profile);
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public View postUser(ModelMap data, @Valid Profile profile, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("No errors");
            return dummyDataView;
        }

        data.put(DummyDataView.DATA_TO_SEND, "users/user-1.json");
        profileService.save(profile);
        return dummyDataView;
}
```

Edit:
This is the Profile. I am testing the sex now so I guess thats what is important.

```
package no.tine.web.tinetips.domain;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import no.tine.web.tinetips.util.CommonRegularExpressions;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;


@Entity
public class Profile {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull(message = "profile.email.null")
    @NotBlank(message = "profile.email.blank")
    @Size(max = 60, message = "profile.email.maxlength")
    @Pattern(regexp = CommonRegularExpressions.EMAIL, message = "profile.email.regex")
    @Column(name = "Email", unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Pattern(regexp = "^[M|F]{1}$", message = "profile.sex.regex")
@Size(max = 1, message = "profile.sex.maxlength")
private String sex;


}
```

Comment: show your Profile class source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you instantiated a POJO with `this.userController = new UserController()`, then called its method `this.controller.postUser(...)`. Just simple Java with a simple object, without any relation to Spring and Spring MVC : @Valid is not taken into account.

If you want to make it work, you will have to give your test class some Spring information, with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` and `@ContextConfiguration(...)`. Then, for the Spring MVC part, you will have to mock a request call on your Controller through some Spring MVC facilites. It is done differently if you use Spring MVC 3.0- or 3.1+. For more information and actual code, [see this post and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12308721/400545), for example.

Comment: I am using @ContextConfiguration(...) and @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class). My controller does not take any Request by now. Maybe I should change that.

Comment: @user874774 The controller by itself is fine, it is how you call it in your unit test that doesn't work. You can't just do `this.controller.postUser(...)`. See the link I have given you to know how to call it.

Comment: Where can I find the jar for the framework. The dependency on the GIT hub site cant be resolved.